# Array<Type> VS Type[] in Typescript

Tags: typescript

As far as I know a property's type can be defined in two ways when it's an Array.

```
property_name: type
```

where type can be either

```
Array<string>, Array<MyType>, etc. (e.g. let prop1: Array<string>)
```

and

```
string[], MyType[], etc. (e.g. let prop1: string[])
```

What is the **difference** between the two cases? Or am I misunderstanding something (perhaps something about <> used in casting?)

**EDIT** since the question is marked as duplicate, I am aware there is the other question about any[] but still I had a look at it before posting and to me it was more about the type 'any' than the different [] VS <> I asked

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Typescript Array vs any\[\]](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15860715/typescript-array-vs-any)

Comment: They are practically the same constructs, and are effectively the same objects at runtime. [Reflect-metadata](https://github.com/rbuckton/ReflectDecorators) will also treat them both as having the `Array` object as their constructor. See the above linked answer.

Comment: @NitzanTomer that question is out-of-date -- `Array<T>` didn't exist back then.

Comment: @NathanShively-Sanders the answer is the same with or without the generics because this question can be reduced to "what's the different between `let x: Array;` to `let x: any[];`"

Answer (score 443, accepted):

## There isn't any semantic difference

There is no difference at all. `Type[]` is the **shorthand syntax** for an array of `Type`. `Array<Type>` is the **generic syntax**. They are completely equivalent.

The handbook provides [an example here](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html#working-with-generic-type-variables). It is equivalent to write:

```
function loggingIdentity<T>(arg: T[]): T[] {
    console.log(arg.length);
    return arg;
}
```

Or:

```
function loggingIdentity<T>(arg: Array<T>): Array<T> {
    console.log(arg.length);
    return arg;
}
```

And here is a quote from [some release notes](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#a-new-syntax-for-readonlyarray):

> Specifically, `number[]` is a shorthand version of `Array<number>`, just as `Date[]` is a shorthand for `Array<Date>`.

### About the `readonly` type modifier

TypeScript 3.4, introduces the `readonly` type modifier. With [a precision](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#caveats):

> the `readonly` type modifier can only be used for syntax on array types and tuple types

```
let err2: readonly Array<boolean>; // error!    
let okay: readonly boolean[]; // works fine
```

The following declaration is equivalent to `readonly boolean[]`:

```
let okay2: ReadonlyArray<boolean>;
```

Comment: thank you for the answer. could you please clarify what is exactly the <T> in loggingIdentity<T>?

Comment: @dragonmnl, It is a generic type. Just read the section "Hello World of generics" in [the Handbook](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html).

Comment: I think we're all agreed there is no functional difference, but has there been any recommendation on what is the preferred style?

Comment: There isn't an official recommendation. I personally use the shorthand and only the shorthand (`type[]`), because it is easier to read.

Comment: I like to look at Angular's official style guide for guidance on these sorts of things.
https://angular.io/guide/styleguide
  
Secondly, I look at the Angular Material code base.
https://github.com/angular/components
  
**References to array as: `Array<type>`**:
styleguide: 0
ng-material: 35
  
**References to array as: `type[]`**:
styleguide: 2
ng-material: 532

So for myself, I'd go for `type[]`, since it's what the Angular team seem to lean towards.

Comment: They aren't _completely_ identical anymore: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#caveats

Comment: Also, TSLint may be configured to only allow the `T[]` notation if `T` is a _simple_ type, and require the `Array<T>` notation if `T` is a complex type: https://palantir.github.io/tslint/rules/array-type/

Comment: If I got it right, in `readonly` case it's not actually required. If you prefer a long notation you can write it like this:
`let err2: ReadonlyArray<boolean>;`

Comment: @n4nn31355 I think so. I edited to add this notice.

Comment: Array<T> came first and is backwards compatible with older typescript versions. Not that I can think of any reason you would want to move backwards with Typescript.

Comment: Another difference is that T[] cannot be used as a base interface.

Comment: Cool think is also to look at how google have defined this standard:
https://google.github.io/styleguide/tsguide.html#arrayt-type

Answer (score 7):

There is a difference when you are defining fixed length arrays. You can't define a fixed length array with `Array<>`, you have to use the shorthand syntax:

```
const myFunc1 = (arg: [string, number, boolean]) => {
  console.log(arg);
};
myFunc1(["hello world", 123, true]);

// error: TS2314: Generic type 'Array ' requires 1 type argument(s).
const myFunc2 = (arg: Array<string, number, boolean>) => {
  console.log(arg);
};
myFunc2(["hello world", 123, true])
```

Comment: Its also called tuples https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#tuple-types was going to write that its not a fixed size array, but it actually is, still definition is IMO misleading. Fixed size array would look like `const arr = new Array<number>(3);`, though technically it will not be fixed ofc

Comment: The "fixed length arrays" are an entirely different feature. So, no there is no difference when using the actual array type syntax. You're describing [Difference between type\[\] and \[type\] in TypeScript](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36741917)