# how to nest an array of type alias in a type alias in typescript?

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-types

```
type subProp = {
  id: string,
  name: string
};

type ParentProps = {
  subscriptions?: [
    {
      id: string,
      items: [???Array Of subProp???]
    }
  ]
}
```

Is this case doable in typescript with only type alias? If so, how to do it? I can't find any viable option online. If no, what's the alternative?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can declare `items` as an `array` of `subProps` and `subscriptions` as an array of a type with `id` and `items`:

```
type subProp = {
  id: string,
  name: string
};

type ParentProps = {
    subscriptions?: {
        id: string,
        items: subProp[];
    }[];  
}
```

Comment: what is this `XXX[ ]` syntax calls? I want to look into it and learn more! thanks

Comment: It just means that it's an array of type `XXX`. Another way to do this is: `items: Array<subProp>`, see: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#array and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36842158/arraytype-vs-type-in-typescript