# undefined[] is missing the following properties from type

Tags: angular, typescript

I have this error when I try to assign an empty value to an array whose type was already declared. Here is the code that causes the error,

```
export interface EmiCalculator {
    emi: number;
    months: number;
    position: number;
    principal: number;
    roi: number;
}
```

Below is the line that produces the error,

```
emiResults: EmiCalculator = [];
```

How can I assign an empty array to a property whose type was already declared.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`EmiCalculator` is an object, `[]` is an array. You probably want an array of `EmiCalculator` which can be written as `EmiCalculator[]` or `Array<EmiCalculator>`

```
export interface EmiCalculator {
    emi: number;
    months: number;
    position: number;
    principal: number;
    roi: number;
}
const emiResults: EmiCalculator[] = [];
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBASwHY2FAZgQwMbDgUQFsEBhTAG2wFdzMZo4BvAKDjbmGIC44krCARmgDcrdoQgoAFgGcefQSLFtIMhDAST5-IVFHs4YKMmwIwFbYr3K4UCAku7RAX2bZJM+JwQAlYDJoYOQJiMkoaOmgAbQBdOABeOFjhIA)

Comment: what is the difference between Array<EmiCalculator> = []; & emiResults: EmiCalculator[]

Comment: @anonymous none, different way to write the same type

Comment: Thanks for answering.

Answer (score 1):

You are assign an array to an object.

An Interface essentially define the structure for an object, so you can't assign an array to an object.

What you might be looking for is

```
emiResults: Array<EmiCalculator> = [];
```

Comment: what is the difference between Array<EmiCalculator> = []; & emiResults: EmiCalculator[]

Comment: [There is a few minor differences](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36842158/arraytype-vs-type-in-typescript), but in your case, it does not matter

Comment: Thanks for answering. Upvoted your answer. Could not accept more than two answers.

Comment: It's fine, Titian was faster than me and their answer is pretty good.

Answer (score -1):

When you write

```
emiResults: EmiCalculator = [];
```

you are assigning an empty array to a variable `emiResults` whose type is defined to be `EmiCalculator`.

Interface defines the structure of an object. So the type of `emiResults` is object. But you are assigning an array.

You may want to do either of the following.

```
let emiResults: EmiCalculator[] = [];
```

or you can use the Typescript generic syntax,

```
let emiResults: Array<EmiCalculator> = [];
```

Comment: How is your answer different than others? They are exactly same as others posted here.

Comment: Yes, the answer is the same. I just wanted to explain a bit.