# If there is no syntactical difference between Array<type> and type[], which one should I use and why?

Tags: arrays, typescript, types

If I have an array variable in TypeScript, should I use `Array<type>`  or `type[]` to define that array? I have seen elsewhere that there is no syntactical difference, but if that is the case, then which one should I use in general and why?

Edit: Several people have suggested [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36842158/arraytype-vs-type-in-typescript). While it confirms that the two are syntactically identical, it hasn't helped me determine which version to actually use in my programs. (I'm not sure if opinion-oriented questions are unpopular on SO, but that is essentially what I'm asking - which one do most people prefer to use, and is there a reason for that?)

Comment: Dupe of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36842158/arraytype-vs-type-in-typescript / opinion based

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Array<Type> VS Type\[\] in Typescript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36842158/arraytype-vs-type-in-typescript)

Comment: @CertainPerformance I saw that one, but it didn't help me figure out which one to use, only that they are identical. Are opinion-based questions not allowed on SO? I guess that is what I'm asking - if they are syntactically identical, is there one that most people prefer to use?

Comment: Different people prefer different styles. I don't know the statistics. No, opinion-based questions aren't allowed here.

Comment: Use a linter to encourage consistency.  I use `type[]` mainly because that's the default linting rule.

Comment: If you ever need to compile React, the `< >` characters can be mistaken for JSX, so you might as well get used to writing `let myNumbers : number[]`