# How to resolve type error UseRef's current?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, use-ref

I am struggling with type error from UseRef's current.
Here is my code, the error happens in the last line (idnList.current)
[ ERROR CODE ] TS2322: Type 'IdnListProps[]' is not assignable to type 'never[]'.

```
const idnList = useRef([]);  
 
const _idnList: ({id:string, label:string})[] = [];
 if (_defaultIdn) { idnList.push({id:"id",label:"label"}) } 
idnList.current = _idnList;
```

How can I solve this type error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to specify this type in useRef

```
const idnList = useRef<Array<{id:string, label:string}>>([])
 const _idnList: ({id:string, label:string})[] = [];
        if (_defaultIdn) {
           _idnList.push({id,label})
         } 
   idnList.current = _idnList;
```

Comment: wow...finally solved..thanks a lot !! I will accept your answer in 10 min

Comment: [it should be the same](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36842158/arraytype-vs-type-in-typescript) :) i prefer to use Array<>

Comment: Oh THKs! :-)! everything clear ( prev comments deleted by mistakes.. )