# TypeScript what is the difference between any[] and Array<any> and when should I use which one?

Tags: arrays, typescript

I'm a bit confused when it comes to defining arrays in TypeScript, because I don't understand the difference between `any[]` and `Array<any>`.

I read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15860715/typescript-array-vs-any) in hope to gain some understanding, but it didn't enlighten me. And I can't seem to find any general sources that describes this.

When should I be using `any[]` and when should I use `Array<any>`? Does it even matter which one I use?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Array<Type> VS Type\[\] in Typescript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36842158/arraytype-vs-type-in-typescript)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no difference to the generated Javascript. It's a matter of style.